# Why does 'this' refer to the object 'obj' not global object

Tags: javascript, object, scope, global, arrow-functions

```
var obj = {
  name: 'hello',
  getName: function(){
  return () => {return this.name; }
  }
}
var name = 'world';
var nameFunc = obj.getName();
console.log(nameFunc())
```

And the result is "hello",not "world".
I am a little confused.

Comment: You would get `"world"` with `(0,obj.getName)()()`.

Answer (score 5):

Arrow functions are "born" bound to the value of `this` as it was at the time of their creation. When you make your call to `getName()`:

```
var nameFunc = obj.getName();
```

then inside `getName()` the value of `this` is a reference to `obj`.  Your `return` statement constructs the arrow function, and that function is therefore bound to `obj`. It's as if you'd written:

```
  getName: function() {
    return function() {
      return this.name;
    }.bind(this);
  }
```

That's just the way arrow functions work, and yes it's different from regular functions.